# how to return a binary image from an aws lambda proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

have an api gateway and a python lambda using proxy integration.  have added a binary type of image/jpeg in the lambda settings.

have the following code in the lambda:

```py
        image ="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"
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": image,
            "headers": {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"},
            "isBase64Encoded": True
        }
```

The code and lambda work with html files, with json files - but this just doesn't work at all - if you browse to that address in a browser - you just get a little white square.

This seems to be exactly according to the documentation.
Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Your `image` seems very small. Are you sure that this is not the little white square actually?

Comment: I'm sure. - it's a small image I picked for this purpose